# How to select a number from all the integers list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to find the numbers from all the integers list such that these will satisfy the condition. Ex:

```
Select[{1,3,8,9},#^3==27&]
```

But instead of giving {1,3,8,9} I want to give all the integers.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html):

```
FindInstance[x^3 == 27, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 3}}
> ```

Although not necessary in this case you can restrict the domain with the third parameter, i.e. `FindInstance[x^3 == 27, x, Integers]`.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply

```
Solve[x^3 == 27, x, Integers]
```

> {{x -> 3}}

?

Comment: For some reason I had in mind a case with infinite solutions, but `Solve` is more direct here.  In any case it seems we are guessing what the OP wants.